# Read returned bytes in web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, testing, truffle-contract

I have a simple contract with a function that should return a `byte32` which is passed as a parameter.

This is a snippet of my contract

```
contract SimpleContract{
   function simple(byte32 toReturn, byte32 otherArg) public returns (byte32){
        //Work with the values
        return toReturn; //Unmodified
   }
}
```

Now, if I test it in Solidity, works seamlessly, but since I want to run more complex test, I turned to Truffle and used its JS library to run the test. Specifically, `simple` is tested this way:

```
contract("SimpleContract", function(accounts){
   it("should return the passed value", function (){
       SimpleContract.deployed().then(function(instance){
          var arg1 = 0xec40808d22324ec2fd140c398284c2a263871d111f54eb6f1b308c874ea1abc9;
          var arg2 = 0x1234567890;
          instance.simple.call(arg1, arg2).then(function(returnedValue){
              expect(returnedValue).to.equal(arg1);
          });
       });
   });
});
```

Then I get this error:

```
AssertionError: expected 'ec40808d22324ec2fd140c398284c2a263871d111f54eb6f1b308c874ea1abc9' to equal '0xbd4419d46aafe6c72f31a89e54fd9976c34fe7cd385253d36e4226f94376e6dd'
```

I suspect there is some encoding issue, but I still haven't been able to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Your function should be declared as constant `function simple(bytes32 toReturn, bytes32 otherArg) public constant returns (bytes32)`

Comment: Also isn't  `byte32` is `bytes32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test passes for me when run under the latest `truffle` version 

`Truffle v4.0.0-beta.2 (core: 4.0.0-beta.2)
Solidity v0.4.17 (solc-js)`

I haven't tried earlier versions.

Comment: The issue happened with truffle 3.4.11, upgrading fixed it. I didn't find what was changed to fix this, but it seems to me that it was some truffle issue.